# Save timer to local memory in Flutter and calculate time when needed

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with DateTime
When I press the button, I save the hour and minute in memory, then when I log into the application, I take the current hour and minute and subtract it from the saved one, subtracting the result from the time I specified earlier. If the remaining time is equal to zero, the program stops, otherwise the remaining time is displayed on the screen.
But I'm very bad at this, can you share an example output similar to this if you have it?

Tried many things but failed

Comment: The memory will be cleared when you close the program, you need to save the DateTime using shared_preferences or other means

Comment: Yes, I save using shared preferences. but I couldn't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the time as a shared_preferences as follows:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
await prefs.setString('time', currentTime.toString());
```

When you want to read the recorded value and to calculate the difference

```
final String? time = prefs.getString('time');
DateTime oldTime = DateTime.parse(time??"0");
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();
currentTime.difference(oldTime);
```